# query and update a stream in flink stream sql

Tags: apache-flink

I am looking for a solution based on flink, the situation is that I have a trans stream and some rules which can be expressed as SQL, I want to update the stream after query(if matched ruleSql1 set this transEvent respCode = 01; if matched ruleSql2 then set this transEvent respCode = 02; respCode has priority).

The question is：

1. By flink sql I can get a result, but how to feedback the result to original stream, the output I expected is original stream with different respCode.
2. I have a lot of rules, how to merge the result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Flink's operators have streams coming in, and transformed streams coming out. It's not clear exactly what you want -- but whether you want to modify each event to add a field with the response code, or something else, it's easily done. If you are using SQL, simply describe the output you want in the SELECT clause.
2. You can use `split/select` to make *n* copies of your stream, and then apply one of your rules (expressed as a SQL query) to each of these parallel copies. Then you can use `union` to merge them back together (provided they are all of the same type).

You'll find the documentation on split, select, and union [in this section of the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/stream/operators/#datastream-transformations).

The [Flink training site](https://training.data-artisans.com/) has a sequence of hands-on exercises that you may find helpful in learning how the pieces of the API fit together, though none that use split/select/union.